# Opera 15 and 16 ctrl+enter does not autocomplete

Tags: opera-next

I just upgraded Opera to version 16 and ctrl+enter suddenly does not work anymore.
Is there a way to put this behavior back to Opera 15/16? Since in all major browser ctrl+enter auto add .com for you in the address field. It is somewhat annoying that it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

New Opera is automatically saving your filled data the way Chrome does. On top of that you can define your own data to be prefilled in **Settings > Privacy & Security > Autofill**, there you can create either address or credit card prefill data. You'll be offered the possible values when focusing/clicking the respective input element and type the first letter of the value type (firstname, surname....).